# Docker RUN mkdir -p creates subdirectories with { in them

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my docker file I have this command to create directories :

```
RUN   mkdir -p logs/{shell,security,errors}
```

However, it ends up creating these on my container :

{shell,security,errors}

How can I create directories without also including the curly braces?

Comment: Bash brace expansion isn't part of the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).  Split out the directory names as individual arguments.

Comment: RUN use shell, not bash, only bash has expansion using "{}"

Comment: @Daniel Baker Accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with shell for loop

```
RUN for i in shell security errors; do  mkdir "/logs/$i"; done
```

This should work.